# htpasswd inaccurate check

Tags: apache, nginx, .htpasswd

I found an interesting thing. I've setup Nginx for Base Auth with htpasswd file. Everything works fine, but the passwords like `<correct password><some random chars>` gain access as well as `<correct password>`.

Is it OK? It is an Nginx-only issue, or is it related to the crypt method used in both Nginx and Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shared this with our servers administrator. And he's found the answer:
`crypt` algorithm hashes only first 8 characters, so if your password is lengthier than 8 chars it does not improve it's falsification-resistance.
If your password is 6-symbols length, let's say

> passwd

Basic auth will refuse password like `passwd01`

If you use `htpasswd` utility and want your passwords to be lengthier than 8 symbols to improve it's cryptography strength, you better encrypt them using `md5` or `sha` algorithm (`-m` and `-s` modifiers respectively).

So your proposition

> is it related to the crypt method used in both Nginx and Apache

is correct

Proof can be found at [`GNU.org libc 32.3 Encrypting Passwords`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/crypt.html):

> For the DES-based algorithm, the salt should consist of two characters from the alphabet ./0-9A-Za-z, and the result of crypt will be those two characters followed by 11 more from the same alphabet, 13 in total. **Only the first 8 characters in the key are significant**.